# How to fix this error when running home menu with work with plus?

Tags: genexus, workwithplus

I got this error when after installing work with plus and running the menu. Is there anyway to fix this problem. Thank you[image]

Comment: Open `GetHomeSampleData` object and check the rules section to see if there is a `parm` rule there. If it's commented or you see none then check the history of that object for modifications or reimport it again

Comment: @gusbro yeah I don't see the parm rule but I don't have any rule to begin with, the other fellows in my group also don't have the parm rule but their app still run normally!

Comment: Check the events section of the `Home` webpanel at line 19. What does it say ?

Comment: @gusbro &HomeSampleData = GetHomeSampleData()

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the Home webpanel. All the error just point to the GetHomeSampleData DP

Comment: Ok, I didn't know `GetHomeSampleData` was a dataprovider. In that case it does not need a `parm` rule because the output is implicit (defined in the `Output` property of the dataprovider). I would try creating a new DataProvider, set the output property just as it is defined in the problematic dataprovider and put some dummy data, then change the statement in your `Home` webpanel at line 19 to point to this new dataprovider. It seems that somehow the signature for `GetHomeSampleData` got corrupted.

Comment: It doesn't work, maybe my computer has some problem? I have tried to reinstall both genexus and WWP but it seems like this never work for me

Comment: I am certainly sure its not your computer, but I have not enough information to help you either.  Which version of GeneXus are you using, including the build number as shown in Help->About ?

Comment: I'm using GeneXus 17 trial version, it's the latest version and also the latest trial version of WWP. I don't think my installation have issues since I and my fellow follow the same process but I got this bug and he didn't :(

Comment: I don't even change anything after installing WWP, and how come this error appear

Comment: This is all about my version. GeneXus Trial - Version: 17.0.162473 U10